# I cannot play video DVDs on Fedora 32

Tags: linux, video, fedora, dvd

I am not able to mount and play video DVDs on my HP ProBook 450 G2 laptop with Fedora 32 with the current KDE 5.18 as the desktop environment, since they do not get detected. Other kinds of DVDs work fine. If I try to mount a video DVD, it says:

```
    mount: /media/dvd: no medium found on /dev/sr0
```

If I run `dmesg` afterwards, I get:

```
    [104424.988293] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0] tag#15 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE cmd_age=0s
    [104424.988297] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0] tag#15 Sense Key : Not Ready [current] 
    [104424.988300] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0] tag#15 Add. Sense: Incompatible medium installed
    [104424.988303] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0] tag#15 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 01 00
    [104424.988307] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sr0, sector 4 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
    [104424.988311] Buffer I/O error on dev sr0, logical block 1, async page read
    [104425.011320] Buffer I/O error on dev sr0, logical block 0, async page read
```

The DVD related libraries such as libdvdcss, libdvdnav and libdvdread are installed on my system. What can I do to be able to play video DVDs?

Comment: Install a dvd player: `dnf install vlc` ... **vlc** is in the "RPM Fusion Free" repo https://rpmfusion.org/Configuration/ ... Insert DVD → Select VLC when the DVD dialog appears.

Comment: Since DVd is not detected, no dialog appears and trying to play it directly from VLC also does not help, because "Playback failure:
DVDRead could not open the disc "/dev/sr0".
Your input can't be opened:
VLC is unable to open the MRL 'dvd:///dev/sr0'. Check the log for details."

Comment: A DVD should open automatically with MATE-Desktop (and Gnome3, I guess), but not necessarily In KDE. .... Which Desktop are you using ? Please edit your question with the Desktop Manager specs https://superuser.com/posts/1552814/edit .... One more thing : Do not attempt to mount a DVD / Music cd, if you want to play the content.

Comment: I am using KDE, I have just included it into the question. I didn't try to mount the DVD before attempting to play it with VLC, but I had tried it earlier, since I had thought the error message could be useful.

Comment: OK, KDE. I made a test yesterday with Fedora32, KDE : I used command line → `$ vlc run/media/[my name]/XXXxxx` → Select "disc"  ..... Now today: I didn't get the automount setting in 'System Settings' to work. ... But you can open VLC, and select 'disc' in the Dialog, and click 'Play'.

Comment: Does this specific DVD play in a different player?  Also, does your laptop play other DVDs?

Comment: @KnudLarsen The DVD doesn't appear in the /run/media/username path, even if I enable the automount setting in System Settings. When I try to play to play the DVD directly from VLC, I get the error message mentioned above.

Comment: @Slartibartfast Yes, this DVD does play in a DVD player connected to my TV.  No, my laptop doesn't play (or detect) any video DVDs, but it can read other kinds of data from standard DVD-R(W)s.